# How much is the visa fee for Indonesian Citizens travelling to Bangladesh

Tags: visas, indonesian-citizens, bangladesh

I would like to know the Bangladeshi visa fee for Indonesian citizens coming to Bangladesh for a short vacation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quoted on the website of [Bangladesh High Commission in London](http://www.bhclondon.org.uk/Visa.html) as £18. The list of visa fees is at the bottom of the page.